# Importing styles from meteor into React Storybook

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, reactjs

I am trying to set up react storybook with my meteor 1.4 project that has the package twbs:bootstrap3 and some custom styles.

After reading the info from the link to set up styles [here](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-storybook/blob/master/docs/setting_up_for_css.md) I have the following code:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.less?$/,
        loader: ["style", "css", "less"],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loader: ["style", "raw"],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      },
   }
}
```

Here is my story

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf, action } from '@kadira/storybook';
import { styles } from './shared';
import HomeSearch from '../features/Search/components/HomeSearch/HomeSearch.jsx';

storiesOf('HomeSearch', module)
  .add('normal', () => { 
      return getItem();
    });


function getItem() {
  return <HomeSearch /> 
}
```

But I am not sure how to import those "packed" styles into the stories.

Comment: The code you have in the first snippet is your webpack configuration for the css loaders (which you need to install with npm). You still need to build the stylesheet. I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are asking.

Comment: @nicholaschris I am unfamiliar with how webpack works, I want to take the styles from my meteor project and use them in my Storybook stories. The info provided in the link I posted just gave me that code (or rather the code to import .css files, I am assuming I amended correctly for less and sass). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS is pre-compiled, and global, you can add the  tags in a custom preview-head.html file. see: https://storybook.js.org/configurations/add-custom-head-tags/

If the CSS is non global, or needs to be processed, you need to add the correct loaders to the custom webpack config. see https://storybook.js.org/configurations/custom-webpack-config/